# Are all JMC ships red?

Tags: red-dwarf

Red Dwarf is a colossal (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf_spacecraft) 6 miles long) mining vessel. I'm curious as to whether it was named "Red Dwarf" because of a unique colour scheme (or more likely painted a unique colour because of it's name) or if all JMC ships are red and the convenient naming is a happy coincidence?

I'm after in-universe views as I think the production decision is fairly logical.

Answer (score 3):

It's not immediately apparent whether the Red Dwarf was named *after* its distinctive colour scheme or whether it was coloured to fit in with its distinctive name.

That said, given that the ship had several shuttles; [Blue Midget](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/database/ships/images/BlueMidgetA1.jpg) (coloured blue), [White Midget](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/database/ships/images/WhiteMidget1.jpg) (coloured white) and [White Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf_spacecraft#White_Giant) (presumably coloured white) it seems likely that the name was chosen first, then the ship's owners (the Jupiter Mining Corp) decided to run with the joke.

Notably, at least one other JMC branded ship we see (a post [probe](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/database/ships/images/PostPod1.jpg)) is also coloured brick red.

Comment: It's also worth noting that they had several shuttles called [Starbug](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/Starbug) which doesn't meet the pattern (unless it's bug green, which I guess makes sense), and the post probe looks like it's based on a sideways [British post box](https://www.safe.co.uk/safezone/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/iStock_000013684087XSmall.jpg) with a rocket on the bottom, rather than being a JMC design.

Answer (score 2):

The only reference made in the programme to other ships was the *Leviathan*, which was buried in a glacier so no colour was seen.  On the occasions when Rimmer mentioned people he trained with who had gone on to better things, no ship name was mentioned.

I would suggest that the colour was chosen to highlight the joke in the opening credits of the first series whereby Lister is painting the outside of the ship red.  A reference to the adage about continuously painting the Forth Bridge - which is famously red.  The name would then have been chosen to be appropriate for the colour.

Comment: I'm fairly sure other ships are mentioned - didn't Holly play chess against the computer from the Scott??? Fitzgerald? Don't remember anything about colour though

Comment: Thinking further - there was one ship - I've edited the answer.